# Perforce API: Repository.GetChangeLists returns lists with no files

Tags: c#, api, perforce

I am using p4api.net (version 2015.1.105.4164) trying to retrieve some changelists affecting a certain path.
My problem is: All the lists returned declare to have no files at all, which is pretty paradox, as a change list without a file affected does not really represent a change at all. In P4V, the changelists returned of course show at least one file.

What am i doing wrong? Why is the Files.Property of each returned change list always empty?

```
  private void ListSubmittedChangeLists(string path, string client, string user, int maxLists)
  {
     ChangesCmdFlags flags = ChangesCmdFlags.IncludeTime & ChangesCmdFlags.FullDescription;
     var options = new Options(flags, client, maxLists, ChangeListStatus.Submitted, user);
     IList<Changelist> lists = Repository.GetChangelists(options, new FileSpec(new DepotPath(path), VersionSpec.Head));
     Console.WriteLine("{0} lists found.", lists.Count);
     foreach (Changelist list in lists)
     {            
        Console.WriteLine("{0} files found in changelist {1}.", list.Files.Count, list.Id);
        foreach (FileMetaData file in list.Files)
        {               
           Console.WriteLine(file.ClientPath);
        }
     }
     Console.WriteLine("Done.");
     Console.ReadLine();
  }
```

EDIT: I found a workaround: For each changelist returned, i have to call Repository.GetChangeList(list.Id); this returns a list object that has its Files collection filled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround that you describe in your edit to your question is, in fact, the correct answer.

`GetChangelists` returns summary information about the change, but not information about each file in the change. `GetChangeList` returns the detailed information about the files in the change.

Comment: I really do not understand how that could be the preferred way of working. It is the same type i am getting, therefore one would expect the same functionality. Anyway, thx!

Comment: I agree, it's an odd behavior. Here's how I conceptualize it: the `GetChangelists` method constructs the "skeleton" of each changelist description, including the author, date, description, etc., while the `GetChangeList` method fills in the details. For what it's worth, the two different methods actually access different tables in the server's database, running different queries to do so. Some applications, for some purposes, only want that "skeletal" information, so the applications that need the complete details are required to make the extra query.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, but it would have been more intuitive to show this by returning another type via GetChangeLists(maybe an ancestor that does not implement the Files property), or just to throw an exception with a hint what to do if triggering the files property. It seems the perforce guys have their own special way of programming APIs (especially when i think of the horrible way of passing params to different methods: one options type to call them all)...